# linux dup2 doens't seem to work with pipe?

Tags: linux, redirect, input, pipe, dup2

I was trying dup2 on linux. My test program is: I open a pipe, try to dup stdin to fifo write, dup stdout to fifo read, I wish when I run this program, the stdin is writen into the fifo, and fifo automatically dumps the content to stdout:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(){
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);
    int& readfd=pipefd[0];
    int& writefd=pipefd[1];
    dup2(STDIN_FILENO,writefd);
    dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,readfd);

    char buf[1024];
    scanf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I run this program, didn't see an extra stdout print. My question:

(1) Is my stdin "scanf" being writen to fifo writefd?

(2) If yes, could the content be auto-directed to my console output? If not how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get [man dup2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) right, the `dup2(oldfd, newfd)` system call creates a copy of `oldfd` file descriptor numbered `newfd`, silently closing `newfd` if it was previously open. So your `dup2(STDIN_FILENO,writefd)` line closes the write end of the pipe and replaces it with a copy of stdin. The next line does the same for the read end and stdout, respectively. So you don't get your stdin and stdout connected through pipe. Instead, you create a pipe and then close both its ends and replace them with copies of your original stdin and stdout descriptors. After that your `scanf("%s",buf);` just reads a string from the original stdin as usual. You can add a line like `printf("%c\n", buf[1])` just after that, and it will print the second character of the string to the original stdout. Note that at that point, in fact there is no pipe created with `pipe(pipefd)` — both its ends was already closed.